# How do I get started with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Are there any good resources to get started with Node.JS? Any good tutorials, blogs or books?

Of course, I have visited its official website http://nodejs.org/, but I didn't think the documentation they have is a good starting point.

Comment: If and of you are wondering on how to build a website using node.js and you're coming from a php'ish background, I've asked how to do _that_ here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311672/building-a-website-using-node-js-best-practice . I feel that's something a lot of people miss.

Answer (score 4698):

You can follow these tutorials to get started:

**Tutorials**

- [NodeSchool.io interactive lessons](http://nodeschool.io/)
- [The Art of Node (an introduction to Node.js)](https://github.com/maxogden/art-of-node/#the-art-of-node)
- [Hello World](http://www.nodebeginner.org/#hello-world)
- [Hello World Web Server](http://www.nodebeginner.org/#building-the-application-stack) (paid)
- [Node.js guide](http://nodeguide.com/)
- [Build a blog with Node.js, express and MongoDB](http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb)
- [Node.js for Beginners](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/node-js-for-beginners/)
- [Learn Node.js Completely and with Confidence](http://javascriptissexy.com/learn-node-js-completely-and-with-confidence/)
- [Node JS Processing Model – Single Threaded Model with Event Loop Architecture](http://www.journaldev.com/7462/node-js-processing-model-single-threaded-model-with-event-loop-architecture)
- [RisingStack's Node Hero Series](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-tutorial-getting-started-with-node-js/)
- [Great Node.js tutorials voted by the programming community](https://hackr.io/tutorials/learn-node-js)
- [Node.js Tutorial](https://www.tutorialkart.com/nodejs/nodejs-tutorial/)
- [30 days of Node](https://www.nodejsera.com/30-days-of-node.html)

**Developer Sites**

- [Joyent's developer site for node](http://www.joyent.com/developers/node)
- [Tutorials Teacher](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/nodejs-tutorials)

**Videos**

- [Node Tuts](http://nodetuts.com/) (Node.js video tutorials)
- [Einführung in Node.js (in German)](https://vimeo.com/thenativeweb)
- [Introduction to Node.js with Ryan Dahl](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jo_B4LTHi3I)
- [Node.js: Asynchronous Purity Leads to Faster Development](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/nodejs)
- [Parallel Programming with Node.js](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Parallel-Programming-with-Nodejs)
- [Server-side JavaScript with Node, Connect & Express](http://vimeo.com/18077379)
- [Node.js First Look](http://www.lynda.com/Nodejs-tutorials/Nodejs-First-Look/101554-2.html)
- [Node.js with MongoDB](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_GNHWZHc-o)
- [Ryan Dahl's Google Tech Talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6k8lTrAE2g)
- [Real Time Web with Node.js](http://node.codeschool.com/levels/1)
- [Node.js Tutorials for Beginners](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBMdkKFn3HasZnnAqVjzHn_)
- [Pluralsight courses (paid)](http://www.pluralsight.com/search/?searchTerm=Node.js)
- [Udemy Learn and understand Nodejs (paid)](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj6oMvR35nTAhWFuY8KHfC-BFoQFggZMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.udemy.com%2Funderstand-nodejs%2F&usg=AFQjCNF3WkS8cFyYrTgzgd5V_S1ANKkZJw&sig2=rD4t8JYDPvQKjwAMzQnH7Q)
- [The New Boston](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-u-j7uqU7sI&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBMdkKFn3HasZnnAqVjzHn_)

**Screencasts**

- [Learn All The Nodes](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQmX5gaHg2SXyKuT9BQ_nbFIdZ39yeRxH)
- [Node Tuts](http://nodetuts.com/)
- [Einführung in Node.js (in German)](https://vimeo.com/thenativeweb)
- [NodeCasts](http://nodecasts.net/)

**Books**

- [The Node Beginner Book](http://nodebeginner.org/)
- [Mastering Node.js](https://github.com/tj/masteringnode)
- [Up and Running with Node.js](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001808/index.html)
- [Node.js in Action](http://www.manning.com/cantelon/)
- [Smashing Node.js: JavaScript Everywhere](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008Z5OEUY)
- [Node.js & Co. (in German)](http://www.amazon.de/dp/389864829X)
- [Sam's Teach Yourself Node.js in 24 Hours](http://nodejsbook.io/)
- [Most detailed list of free JavaScript Books](http://jsbooks.revolunet.com/)
- [Mixu's Node Book](http://book.mixu.net/node/index.html)
- [Node.js the Right Way: Practical, Server-Side JavaScript That Scale](http://pragprog.com/book/jwnode/node-js-the-right-way)
- [Beginning Web Development with Node.js](https://leanpub.com/webdevelopmentwithnodejs)
- [Node Web Development](http://www.packtpub.com/node-javascript-web-development/book)
- [NodeJS for Righteous Universal Domination!](http://node.codeschool.com/)

**Courses**

- [Real Time Web with Node.js](http://node.codeschool.com/)
- [Essential Node.js from DevelopMentor](http://www.develop.com/training-course/nodejs-featuring-node-npm-express-mocha-mongodb-with-mongoose)
- [Freecodecamp - Learn to code for free](https://www.freecodecamp.org/)
- [Udemy - The Complete Node.js Developer Course (3rd Edition) (paid)](https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-nodejs-developer-course-2/)

**Blogs**

- [The Node.js blog](http://blog.nodejs.org/)
- [How To Node](http://howtonode.org/)
- [DailyJS](http://dailyjs.com/)
- [Nodejitsu blog](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/)
- [Ryan Wilcox's Whitepaper](http://www.wilcoxd.com/whitepapers/node_js/)
- [devthought](http://www.devthought.com/)

**Podcasts**

- [NodeUp](http://nodeup.com/)

**JavaScript resources**

- [Crockford's videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7664379246A246CB) (must see!)
- [Essential JavaScript Design Patterns For Beginners](http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/)
- [JavaScript garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/)
- [JavaScript Patterns](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596806767) book
- [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748/) book
- [Eloquent javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/)  book

**Node.js Modules**

- [Search for registered Node.js modules](http://npmjs.org/)
- [A curated list of awesome Node.js libraries](https://github.com/sindresorhus/awesome-nodejs)
- [Wiki List on GitHub/Joyent/Node.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules) (start here last!)

**Other**

- [JSApp.US - like jsfiddle, but for Node.js](http://jsapp.us/)
- [Node with VJET JS (for Eclipse IDE)](https://www.ebayopensource.org/index.php/VJET/NodeJS)
- Production sites with published source:

  - [Node Knockout Hackathon](http://nodeknockout.com/) [(source)](https://github.com/nko3/website)
  - [Freecodecamp - Learn to code for free](https://www.freecodecamp.org/) [(source)](https://github.com/freeCodeCamp/freeCodeCamp)
- [Useful Node.js Tools, Tutorials and Resources](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/16/useful-node-js-tools-tutorials-and-resources/)
- [Runnable.com - like jsfiddle, but for server side as well](http://runnable.com/)
- [Getting Started with Node.js on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/nodejs)
- [Getting Started with Node.js on Open-Shift](https://blog.openshift.com/run-your-nodejs-projects-on-openshift-in-two-simple-steps/)
- [Authentication using Passport](http://passportjs.org/guide/)

Comment: Are the books ordered by your value in them or randomly?  Looking to purchase a good reference manual on nodeJS's basics.

Comment: @David: More or less randomly. First two are freely available and the last one is in preview mode. I would recommend to start with The Node Beginner.

Comment: The second book you list, Mastering Node.js, although its current content is indeed helpful, is just half finished.

Comment: My book (Node up and running) is available for free here: http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449398583/ forever. It's also now an ebook and print.

Comment: Though I'm sure it took a lot of effort to compile this list, it would actually have been a lot more helpful to get no more than 3 of the best places (in your opinion)

Comment: "The node beginner" has unfortunately gone the way of the ... it's pay begging now (or I haven't discovered the "next" button).

Comment: I don't recommend the nettuts tutorial. Their first benchmarked example isn't what you'd use node for. And listening for the `end` event in the `request` stream is unnecessary and will not work with the new streams in node version >= 0.9

Comment: I just published a tutorial on using Node.js to build a complete web application. Check it out at https://leanpub.com/webdevelopmentwithnodejs.

Comment: Visit this website it will get you started on windows http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2012/09/14/node.js-adventure---node.js-on-windows.aspx

Comment: Check out [Beginning Web Development with Node.js](https://leanpub.com/webdevelopmentwithnodejs) for a simple walkthrough of building a complete web application with a database, security, form validation, Bootstrap themes, etc...

Comment: Even it's not a tutorial - I would like to recommend for the beginners to try out the web-online environment https://c9.io/. It has beautiful IDE with debug mode with breakpoints, watches etc, you can develop/upload/download share your project and much more. It's not only NodeJS service, but I didn't try the rest so I can't recommend. NodeJS works just fine there and it's extremely comfortable!

Comment: @sh1mmer: Dead link. This one works (same book): http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001808/index.html

Comment: At a major company my friend works for, "Node.js the Right Way" was the official read. I'd also recommend video tutorials on Lynda. Ya, it's $30, but it covered the tooling very well. Ensure you learn `npm` very thoroughly. It's powerful!

Comment: For someone with no experience in JavaScript (but experience in other languages), what's the best book to learn Node.JS + Javascript?

Comment: I was struggling with this as well, as I couldn't translate a written article into workable code, (I was doing my best not to copy and paste), and I really wanted to learn the concept of Node before going too far in. I found a really great tutorial series on YouTube, I've added it to the Videos list, "Node.js Tutorials for Beginners".

Comment: Here is our get started guide for Node on AWS: https://boxfuse.com/getstarted/nodejs

Comment: For anyone looking for a good understanding of how to build Node Add Ons I can recommend Scott Frees' book "C++ and Node Integration." It's not free but it is really, really helpful if you are trying to understand how C++ code and V8/Javascript interact.

Comment: Taking online classes is another way.  https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/javascript-training-online-object-oriented-courses-mohit-gupta

Comment: These are tons of resources but there is no way to tell which is the best out of the lot. You many want to try Hackr to find out the best Node.js courses/tutorials curated and voted by programming community: https://hackr.io/tutorials/learn-node-js

Comment: I also came out with a Youtube Series on Node Basics:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-4zzaVqc2aj8ZuO9j9kLJdSZnZc3SgSK

Comment: @miparnisari the third link under tutorials, which is same as the first Book listed here - The Node Beginner Book is perfect to learn node.js without javascript knowledge.

Comment: Link http://nicholasjohnson.com/courses/nodejs/book is broken (404).

Comment: Best Node.js Frameworks: https://onaircode.com/best-node-js-frameworks/

Comment: Two more resource for getting started NodeJs: 1. https://onaircode.com/best-nodejs-getting-started-tutorials/   2. https://onaircode.com/nodejs-tools-tutorials-resources/

Comment: w3school nodejs tutorial is the best for newbie. 2nd learn express from w3school. that get you to understand routing and lets you run the server.

Comment: The best place for beginner of node JS is https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_intro.asp

Comment: Code tutorials are all over the place these days. If you really wanna learn you'll find lots of videos on youtube.

Comment: @Internial Do you still think that?

Comment: is there a specific starter kit for node js  with typescript ?

Comment: First need to start with Javascript and then go for Node.

Answer (score 1837):

**First, learn the core concepts of Node.js:**

- [You'll want to understand the asynchronous coding style that Node.js encourages](http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/08/26/asynchronous-code-design-with-node-js/).
- [Async != concurrent. Understand Node.js's event loop](http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/01/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop/)!
- [Node.js uses CommonJS-style require() for code loading; it's probably a bit different from what you're used to](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/what-is-require).
- [Familiarize yourself with Node.js's standard library](http://nodejs.org/api/index.html).

**Then, you're going to want to see what the community has to offer:**

The gold standard for Node.js package management is [NPM](http://npmjs.org/).

- [It is a command line tool for managing your project's dependencies](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/npm/what-is-npm).
- [Make sure you understand how Node.js and NPM interact with your project via the node_modules folder and package.json](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).
- [NPM is also a registry of pretty much every Node.js package out there](http://search.npmjs.org/)

**Finally, you're going to want to know what some of the more popular packages are for various tasks:**

**Useful Tools for Every Project:**

- [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) contains just about every core utility method you want.
- [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com/) is a clone of Underscore that aims to be faster, more customizable, and has quite a few functions that underscore doesn't have. Certain versions of it can be used as drop-in replacements of underscore.
- [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org) makes JavaScript considerably more bearable, while also keeping you out of trouble!
- [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) is a code-checking tool that'll save you loads of time finding stupid errors. Find a plugin for your text editor that will automatically run it on your code.

**Unit Testing:**

- [Mocha](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha) is a popular test framework.
- [Vows](http://vowsjs.org/) is a fantastic take on asynchronous testing, albeit somewhat stale.
- [Expresso](http://visionmedia.github.com/expresso/) is a more traditional unit testing framework.
- [node-unit](https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit) is another relatively traditional unit testing framework.
- [AVA](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ava) is a new test runner with Babel built-in and runs tests concurrently.

**Web Frameworks:**

- [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/) is by far the most popular framework.
- [Koa](http://koajs.com/) is a new web framework designed by the team behind Express.js, which aims to be a smaller, more expressive, and more robust foundation for web applications and APIs.
- [sails.js](https://sailsjs.org) the most popular MVC framework for Node.js, and is based on express. It is designed to emulate the familiar MVC pattern of frameworks like Ruby on Rails, but with support for the requirements of modern apps: data-driven APIs with a scalable, service-oriented architecture.
- [Meteor](http://www.meteor.com/) bundles together jQuery, Handlebars, Node.js, [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), [MongoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB), and DDP and promotes convention over configuration without being a [Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails) clone.
- [Tower](http://towerjs.org/) (*deprecated*) is an abstraction of a top of Express.js that aims to be a Ruby on Rails clone.
- [Geddy](http://geddyjs.org/) is another take on web frameworks.
- [RailwayJS](https://npmjs.org/package/railway) is a Ruby on Rails inspired MVC web framework.
- [Sleek.js](https://sleekjs.com) is a simple web framework, built upon Express.js.
- [Hapi](http://hapijs.com) is a configuration-centric framework with built-in support for input validation, caching, authentication, etc.
- [Trails](http://www.trailsjs.io) is a modern web application framework. It builds on the pedigree of [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) and [Grails](https://grails.org/) to accelerate development by adhering to a straightforward, convention-based, API-driven design philosophy.
- [Danf](https://github.com/gnodi/danf) is a full-stack OOP framework providing many features in order to produce a scalable, maintainable, testable and performant applications and allowing to code the same way on both the server (Node.js) and client (browser) sides.
- [Derbyjs](http://derbyjs.com/) is a reactive full-stack JavaScript framework. They are using patterns like reactive programming and isomorphic JavaScript for a long time.
- [Loopback.io](http://loopback.io/) is a powerful Node.js framework for creating APIs and easily connecting to backend data sources. It has an Angular.js SDK and provides SDKs for iOS and Android.

**Web Framework Tools:**

- [Jade](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade) is the HAML/Slim of the Node.js world
- [EJS](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs) is a more traditional templating language.
- Don't forget about [Underscore's template method](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template)!

**Networking:**

- [Connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) is the Rack or WSGI of the Node.js world.
- [Request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) is a very popular HTTP request library.
- [socket.io](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io) is handy for building WebSocket servers.

**Command Line Interaction:**

- [minimist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimist) just command line argument parsing.
- [Yargs](https://github.com/bcoe/yargs) is a powerful library for parsing command-line arguments.
- [Commander.js](https://github.com/tj/commander.js) is a complete solution for building single-use command-line applications.
- [Vorpal.js](https://github.com/dthree/vorpal) is a framework for building mature, immersive command-line applications.
- [Chalk](https://github.com/chalk/chalk) makes your CLI output pretty.

**Code Generators:**

- [Yeoman](https://yeoman.io) Scaffolding tool from the command-line.
- [Skaffolder](https://www.skaffolder.com) Code generator with visual and command-line interface. It generates a customizable CRUD application starting from the database schema or an OpenAPI 3.0 YAML file.

**Work with streams:**

- [mississipi](https://github.com/maxogden/mississippi) everything you miss about streams.
- https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/streams-a-love-story
- http://maxogden.com/node-streams.html
- https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook
- [How streams help to raise Node.js performance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QgEuZ52OZtU)

Comment: under frameworks you should add http://railwayjs.com/

Comment: @Farm question was about node.js. Angular is a browser framework and is irrelevant here.

Comment: Promise: To write maintainable and readable async code I would recommend https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: Backbone.js, MEAN, Require.js and lots more to come !!! voila!!!

Comment: NodeJS is the future of javascript

Comment: rest API in node ,  my thoughts : https://myroaddiary.wordpress.com/2015/01/16/nodway/

Comment: judging by the number of github stars, Meteor is more popular than Express.

Comment: The best way to lean node js is from scotch.io tutorials. Start from basic CRUD operations then move on to further queries and functionalities.

Comment: A roadmap can be useful in this case like this link:  https://github.com/aliyr/Nodejs-Developer-Roadmap

Answer (score 153):

Use the source, Luke.

No, but seriously I found that building Node.js from source, running the tests, and looking at the benchmarks did get me on the right track. From there, the .js files in the lib directory are a good place to look, especially the file http.js.

Update: I wrote this answer over a year ago, and since that time there has an explosion in the number of great resources available for people learning Node.js. Though I still believe diving into the source is worthwhile, I think that there are now better ways to get started. I would suggest some of the books on Node.js that are starting to come out.

Comment: +1 for the opening line :3 but thats how I leant to use Kohana. So it is a pretty good method as long as you can understand the source.

Comment: Express helps you get started in the source, imo.  I mean, at least it gives you a jumping off point, a working example... something to fiddle around with.  https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html