# From novice to professional: Resources for learning Node.js and Redis

Tags: node.js, redis

Please share your best resources for learning Node.js and Redis.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js

Answer (score 4):

I never found these series of blog posts quoted anywhere, but it seriously helped me get started off real quick with node. http://blog.osbutler.com/categories/node-by-example/?page=3
Its a bit outdated though.

Apart from that, http://howtonode.org and the NodeJS docs.

Comment: +1. Those OSButler tutorials are hands down the best I've seen so far.  However, they seem not to have kept up with all of the node.js changes.  (For example, they use addlistener() which, I believe, has been superceded by on()).  That said, I recommend starting with them (but keep the nodejs.org docs open in another tab).  Then move on to the nodetuts, dailyjs and howtonode tutorials.

Comment: true :) even childprocess has been deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

I will continue to update this list. (But for now  quickly)

- http://camp.nodejs.org/videos/index.html Especially the video "Getting Started with npm: Isaac Schlueter".
- http://nodetuts.com screencasts to learn node.js

Answer (score 1):

I think that Redis [webpage](http://redis.io/) has probably the best [commands](http://redis.io/commands) documentation on the DB market (I really like especially the CLI used within examples). Also [this](http://simonwillison.net/static/2010/redis-tutorial/) tutorial is a must read I would say.

From the node.js point of view I would recommend [Introduction to Redis](http://camp.nodejs.org/videos/session-05_introduction_to_redis-matt_ranney.html) by Matt Ranney and [his](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) Redis client readme and examples.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice extensive tutorial using Node.js together with express and other frameworks: http://www.google.com/search?sitesearch=dailyjs.com&q=node+tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Aaaa.... no http://dailyjs.com/ among the links is a blasphemy! hehe

list of all posts with node tag node tutorials: [http://dailyjs.com/tags.html#node](http://dailyjs.com/tags.html#lmawa)