# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header present AngularJS

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, ajax, node.js

I am trying to build a quick demo site that I do not have control over the server I am trying to connect to. Here is the code that I am using to build it with AngularJS. I am running the file through a simple Python HTTP Server and viewing it at localhost:8000.
    var retrieveAppliances = function () {
        console.log('Attempting to retrieve appliance list.');

```
var requestUrl = '****';
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: requestUrl,
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
};
retrieveAppliances();
```

I have read multiple places to try switching the `method` to `JSONP` but doing so resulted in a parsing error.

While I have considered trying to build a `server.js` file and running NodeJS with it, I am unsuccessful in learning the basics of making an AJAX request and proxying that to my app.js.

I will greatly appreciate any help that someone may be able to give me, with clear and easy to follow steps.

Answer (score 4):

If you're running an Ajax call to a different origin (e.g. different host, port or protocol) and the server at that origin does not have support for cross origin requests, then you cannot fix that from your client.  There is nothing you can do from the client.

If the server supported JSONP, you could use that, but that also requires specific server support.

The only solutions from a browser web page are:

1. CORS support on the target server.
2. JSONP (also requires support on the target server).
3. Set up your own server that you do have access to (either on your existing page domain or with CORS) and then have that server get the file/data for you and proxy it back to you.  You can either write your own proxy or deploy a pre-built proxy.
4. Find some existing third party proxy service that you can use.

If you're interested in making your own node.js proxy, you can see a simple example here: [How to create a simple http proxy in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20354642/816620).

Comment: also third party proxy service is an alternative

Comment: @charlietfl - I added that option.

Comment: Upvoted. Totally agree with the solution. It is not your Web application's problem. This is a server thingy.
@jfriend00 Any chance you can post a small reference for point 4 (third party proxy)? This is something new to me and I would like to learn more about it

Comment: @jfriend00 nvm about it. After reading through again I think I know what you meant by it. Thanks.

Comment: @jfriend00 Would you be able to elaborate and help me set up my own server? Is that something I can do with NodeJS or Python? And if I do get the data, how would I proxy it back to my web app? That's where my knowledge is limited and I begin to hit roadblocks.

Comment: @MichaelDanko - I linked you a specific example of all it takes to implement a simple node.js proxy in my answer.  The basic concept of a proxy is that your client asks the proxy for the web page form the remote server.  The proxy receives that request and then gets the page from the remote server and return it back to the client as the response from the original request.