# How to edit response from website with Nodejs HTTP proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js

So say I'm using a nodejs proxy server, I want it edit the response from a json endpoint. A bit like the fiddler auto-responder, except its in nodejs. For example, say there's the json code "name": "john". I want to use nodejs to edit the response so it says "name": "jane" instead. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please, show us the code what have you been done so far.

Comment: Can you please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351637/how-to-create-a-simple-http-proxy-in-node-js - you can try modifying the request according to your need.

Comment: I want my proxy to intercept the data from the server, edit it, then pass it to the client.