# Call NodeJS function from client-side

Tags: node.js

I have NodeJS on `/` path.

On `/another.ejs` path, I have a little website and I wanna get data from `/value` path.

I cannot do this call with pure JS and AJAX, because of CORS.

Can I do something like when I click on button, it calls function in NodeJS and return data?

Comment: You can enable CORS with [cors npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why CORS is going on in same domain name, but you can try some other ways to get result from routes.

### Using proxy to throw result between server and client.

You can use proxy things.

- [Means creating middle hand (link to another stackoverflow answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351637/how-to-create-a-simple-http-proxy-in-node-js)
- [Also look: PHP: no.php](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjk2OXt2O3iAhWUyosBHdJ3AcoQFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fmichaelfranzl%2Fno.php&usg=AOvVaw2nLy577HazqZh69_tItkTR)

### CORS Module

Also see above comment by [codeherk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6367080/codeherk).