# aws-sdk unable to create bucket No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: amazon-s3, react-tsx

I am unable to create bucket in AWS S3 server using aws-sdk. But I can add new folder and file in existing bucket but not able to create new. Below code, which I used to create a new bucket.

```
import AWS from "aws-sdk";

AWS.config.update({
region: config.region,
 accessKeyId: config.accessKeyId,
 secretAccessKey: config.secretAccessKey,
});
const s3 = AWS.S3();

s3.createBucket({ Bucket: "admin"}, (error, data) => {
  if(error.statusCode === 409){
  upload();
  }
  if (error) {
    console.log(error)
  } else {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you creating a bucket with a name "admin"? If so, change that to a unique name.

Comment: I have tried with different words but still I get same error.

Comment: What is the error message saying?

Comment: This is the exact error I'm getting " Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://intel.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: That says CORS error. Just solve. This may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57009371/access-to-xmlhttprequest-at-from-origin-localhost3000-has-been-blocked

Comment: Can you please be more specific because I'm new to react and the above link says to add cors options in server but I'm just making a request to S3 server using aws-sdk library I followed this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html)

Comment: Perhaps on local machine it works without, right? But on localhost (react) you need to care CORS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I learnt that **this is not possible today**, because browsers enforce CORS restrictions, and AWS SDK has this limitation of treating buckets as resources, hence CORS apply even before they exist.

See https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1112 for more details.

To fix this, you can call createBucket from any non-browser environment (server side), e.g. a lambda function, or a node server or cloud function.