# Angular 13 : has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, opera, swagger-node-express

Can someone help me please, I have a problem in CORS policy and I have no access to the backend of the site.

[image: operaGX navigator console]

This is the code I use in the backend (node.js):

```js
app.use(cors({
  Access_Control_Allow_Origin: "*",
  origin:"*",
  methode:['GET','POST','PATCH','DELETE','PUT'],
  allowedHeaders:'Content-Type, Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Accept'

}));
```

this is the code of the front end (I used Angular 13) to import API:
environment.ts

```js
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  serverURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api/'
};
```

I've tried also this code but it didn't work:

```js
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});
```

Comment: I'd check the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) again. `Access_Control_Allow_Origin` is.. something but not part of the cors package, `methode` is spelled incorrectly, you have `http://localhost:8888` as the allow origin but Angular is running on 4200, etc. Start from the docs and add slowly.

Comment: Willing to bet it is because of `methode`

Comment: i copied this code from an other member response , and i've changed the origin to 4200 on my code, but it didn't work

Comment: Try the second answer. This solved my problem. Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57009371/access-to-xmlhttprequest-at-from-origin-localhost3000-has-been-blocked

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the right imports:

```
var cors = require('cors')

var app = express()
```

and either use:

```
app.use(cors()) // this uses default values
```

Or change your code to this:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});
```

Be careful with '*' as Access-Control-Allow-Origin in production. Change this back only to the clients that are allowed to connect to your API.

If that didn't help, then try to set proxy requests to enable CORS in Angular: Inside the src folder of your application, create a new file called `proxy.conf.json`. This is a JSON file that will contain the configuration for the proxy server. Here, we'll tell our Angular application to act as another server that takes API calls and diverts them to http://localhost:3000.

Inside the proxy.conf.json file, add the following code:

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:3000",
        "secure": false
    }
}
```

Next, inform Angular about this proxy configuration. We can do that by adding a proxyConfig option inside our angular.json file:

```
...
"architect": {
"serve": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
"options": {
"browserTarget": "your-application-name:build",
"proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
}
```

Comment: thnx but it didn't work..

Comment: What errors are you gettings?

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , the API link is working, i test it with "Postman",  but it didn't work on Angular ,

Comment: can you check the code with me if you have time , please it's important

Comment: I modified the answer. Please check if this helps you.

Comment: i had the same problem,  but this one didnt work for me