# CORS policy AWS S3

Tags: angular, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

My frontend (Angular framework) works fine from localhost, but when I launch it from S3, the APIs are all blocked by CORS policy errors.

This is an example error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/v1/sendPasswordRecoveryEmail' from origin 'http://3db-frontend.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space `local`.
```

Right now I launched the frontend on Amazon S3, and I connect to my localhost Spring server (for simplicity).

This is my CORS policy written on S3:

```json
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "x-amz-*",
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "HEAD",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

I expect all requests launched from my Angular environment to be authorized by AWS S3.

Comment: What is at localhost:8080? I'm guessing your app server, running locally. Does it [support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57009371/access-to-xmlhttprequest-at-from-origin-localhost3000-has-been-blocked) CORS?

Comment: This is nothing to do with the AWS S3 CORS policy, that's **not** where those requests are going to.

Comment: jonrsharpe's comment is correct. The error message indicates that the request is coming from S3 and going to your local server. You need to configure your local server (as opposed to your S3 bucket) for CORS (and Private Access Network) for things to work.

Comment: To be clear, the request is coming from the user's browser, not from S3. That request indicates the origin (`http://3db-frontend.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com`) that caused the request.

Comment: @jarmod Yes, perhaps I should have been more specific. When talking about CORS, it's useful to distinguish three actors: the browser, the client (running in the browser in the context of Web origin `http://3db-frontend.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com` here), and the server.

Comment: thanks to all for the replies, i realized that it has nothing to do with aws s3, but my localhost. i am using spring and currently have configured cors requests with a @Bean

Comment: Your Angular app should probably not have access to JWTs. It would better be authorized with sessions on an OAuth2 BFF with proxy providing with SAMEORIGIN for your frontend and the REST API. See this article I wrote for details about why and how: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem is not AWS S3 but my server, I write how I configured CORS permissions:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("http://3db-frontend.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com","https://cangy98.github.io","http://3db-frontend.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com","http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:8080") // Sostituisci con l'origine del frontend
                    .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE","PATCH")
                    .allowedHeaders("*")
                    .allowCredentials(true);
        }
    };
}
```

and this is my security filterChain:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    //ABILITAZIONE CORS-policy DA PROCESSARE NECESSARIAMENTE PRIMA DI SPRING-SECURITY
    http
            .cors(withDefaults())
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .cors(withDefaults())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
                    .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/signin").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/signup").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/v3/api-docs").permitAll()
                    /*.requestMatchers("https://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/v1/create-checkout-session").permitAll()*/
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/v1/collection/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/v1/product/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/v1/jwt/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT,"/v1/autorizzazioni").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/v1/getWelcome").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH,"/v1/verificationEmail/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/v1/verificationEmail/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/v1/sendPasswordRecoveryEmail/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH,"/api/v1/auth/changePassword").permitAll()

                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .sessionManagement(manager -> manager.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider()).addFilterBefore(
                    jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.build();
}
```