# Creating A HTTP proxy server with https support and use another proxy server to serve the response using nodejs

Tags: node.js

I need help creating a proxy server using node js to use with firefox.

the end goal is to create a proxy server that will tunnel the traffic through another proxy server (HTTP/SOCKS) and return the response back to firefox. like this

[image]

I wanna keep the original response received from the proxy server and also wanna support https websites as well.

Here is the code I came up with.

```
var http = require('http');
var request = require("request");
http.createServer(function(req, res){
    const resu = request(req.url, {
        // I wanna Fetch the proxy From database and use it here
        proxy: "<Proxy URL>"
    })
    req.pipe(resu);
    resu.pipe(res);
}).listen(8080);
```

But it has 2 problems.

1. It does not support https requests.
2. It also does not supports SOCKS 4/5 proxies.

EDIT: I tried to create a proxy server using this module. https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy
but the problem is we cannot specify any external proxy server to send connections through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a really super simple solution to the problem. We can just forward all packets as it is to the proxy server. and still can handle the server logic with ease.

```
var net = require('net');
const server = net.createServer()

server.on('connection', function(socket){
    var laddr = socket.remoteAddress;
    console.log(laddr)
    var to = net.createConnection({
        host: "<Proxy IP>",
        port: <Proxy Port>
    });
    socket.pipe(to);
    to.pipe(socket);
});

server.listen(3000, "0.0.0.0");
```

Comment: Nice way. I will try to implement it in my future projects. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use some middleware like http-proxy module.

Documentation here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy

Install it using `npm install node-http-proxy`

This might help too: [How to create a simple http proxy in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351637/how-to-create-a-simple-http-proxy-in-node-js)

Comment: I have looked into this module. The problem is, it doesn't allow me to use another proxy server for handling the outgoing request.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.proxyrack.com/create-your-own-node-js-http-proxy-server-in-under-10-minutes/?

Comment: No. It it not what I wanted.