# How to use puppeteer with browserless and proxy

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, proxy, puppeteer, chromium

I can't figure out how to use puppeteer with browserless and proxy. I keep getting proxy connection errors.

I run browserless in docker like so:

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -e "MAX_CONCURRENT_SESSIONS=5" -e "MAX_QUEUE_LENGTH=0" -e "PREBOOT_CHROME=true" -e "CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=300000" --restart always browserless/chrome
```

Puppeteer options in config I tried to connect with:

```
const args = [
    '--no-sandbox',
    '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
    '--disable-infobars',
    '--window-position=0,0',
    '--ignore-certifcate-errors',
    '--window-size=1400,900',
    '--ignore-certifcate-errors-spki-list',
];

const options = {
    args,
    headless: true,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    defaultViewport: null,
    browserWSEndpoint: `ws://localhost:3000?--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:9055`,
}
```

How I connect:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.connect(config.options);
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('http://example.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }
```

Error I get:

```
Error: net::ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED at http://example.com
    at navigate (C:\...\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\FrameManager.js:115:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
    at async FrameManager.navigateFrame (C:\...\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\FrameManager.js:90:21)
    at async Frame.goto (C:\...\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\FrameManager.js:417:16)
    at async Page.goto (C:\...\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Page.js:825:16)
```

The proxy I'm using in example above is TOR browser, that runs in the background. I can connect through it when I'm not using browserless and use puppeteer.launch() function. I put this proxy in args and everything works fine, the requests are going through tor proxy. I can't figure out know why it doesn't work with browserless and websockets though.

Of course I tried different proxies. I created local proxy in node similar to that [How to create a simple http proxy in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351637/how-to-create-a-simple-http-proxy-in-node-js) (the proxy-server option is then `--proxy-server=http://127.0.0.1:3001`), but the error is the same and I can't even see incoming requests in server's terminal, it looks like they don't even reach a proxy.

I tried public proxies addresses, same error.

Chaninng website I'm trying to connect to in `page.goto()` function doesn't change anything, still get the same error.

I'm beginner at web scraping and run out of options here. Any idea would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it looks like some docker issue. Apparently, there are problems when I'm trying to connect from from browserless inside container to tor which is on host. I used host.docker.internal instead of localhost in connection string and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix the issue specifically with `tor`, you need to make sure that the `torrc` file has `0.0.0.0:9050` open so that you can use it on any network ip otherwise it will only work with localhost. Once you set that, you can pass `socks5://172.17.0.1:9050` to your browserless docker container and it can access the tor proxy form the host system. Keep in mind that the `docker0` ip may be different, run `ip addr show docker0` to find the ip address of the host to use the right one when passing it as the proxy.