# Angular 17 Universal and Express /api/** not working

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I have started a new project with Angular Universal from the CLI.
I would like to redirect the /api/** endpoints to a different server, but I am facing some issues.

I have seen the host is setup in the header of the requests, I change it in the following way:

```
// Example Express Rest API endpoints
  server.get('/api/**', (req, res, next) => {
    req.headers.host = 'http://localhost:3000'
    next();
  });
```

but I get the following error (the endpoint works, I have just copy/pasted the url I and I can get the results):

```
ERROR G [Error]: NG04002: 'localhost:3000/api/news'
    at na.noMatchError (file:///Users/xxxxxx/Development/GitHub/xxxxxx/dist/xxxxxx/server/chunk-JY4VO6WS.mjs:2:39383)
    at file:///Users/xxxxxx/Development/GitHub/xxxxxx/dist/xxxxxx/server/chunk-JY4VO6WS.mjs:2:40078
    at file:///Users/xxxxxx/Development/GitHub/xxxxxx/dist/xxxxxx/server/chunk-RGNQT4QR.mjs:4:21085
```

later in the log I see

```
status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  url: 'http://localhost:4000/api/news',
  ok: false,
  name: 'HttpErrorResponse',
  message: 'Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:4000/api/news',
  error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

as the URL has never been changed.
In the Angular guide I have not seen any example, could you please suggest how to set the rewrite of the host?

Comment: What process is listening on port 3000, what process is listening on port 4000? To which of them does your client connect? And no, you cannot just change the value of the host header on the backend and expect the backend to magically connect to another server. You have to implement some proxy functionality or use a package that provides that functionality for you

Comment: On port 3000 I have a fake backend, on port 4000 the Angular Universal application running (nodejs + express). I have not found any example on the Angular Universal guide, so should I have to add a proxy middleware? do you have any example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351637/how-to-create-a-simple-http-proxy-in-node-js Although this is quite old, the principles are still the same. And searching for "http proxy" on npmjs.com will reveal some packages, take a look and pick the one you like most

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciated, I have used in the past http-proxy-middleware, I think this could make the trick.

Comment: I rolled back as the question post contained the answer. SO's form at is Q&A, one post for each. Feel free to repost as an answer

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

In case someone else will get the same issue as me I post here the solution that works for me.

First thing, in the server.ts file this commented code I think it is for some static response, do not mangle here the req and res parameters as I have done, it does not have any effect if you want to send /api/** to another host:

```js
// Example Express Rest API endpoints
// server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
```

I have installed http-proxy-middleware and configured in this way in server.ts

```js
...
import {createProxyMiddleware} from "http-proxy-middleware";
...

const commonEngine = new CommonEngine();

server.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:3000',
      changeOrigin: true
    })
  );
```

and it works, I will test better in other scenario and see if it is enough.