# what resources do you recommend for learning the following node.js, socket.io, redis mashup

Tags: canvas, node.js, redis, socket.io, tropo

Hi I am interested in building a realtime application. Can you give me some recommended screencasts, ebooks, blog posts for learning these technology (free or paid ones it doesn't matter). I prefer to use these technologies with `PHP` if it's even possible.

Comment: node.js and php can but aren't advised to be used together.  Javascript is the language for node, so I advise learning javascript before diving into node.js

Comment: @Lime thanks!, I have a fair knowledge of javascript

Comment: @Lime if at all possible you should just use node, but both can communicate efficiently using Redis. Especially when you already have a very large code-base in PHP.

Comment: @Lime.  Er, yes PHP can be used with PHP.  You have PHP do it's stuff in the backend and when you want to communicate PHP -> Node you just use CURL and from NodeJS you can do a new http request.  How do I know, because I too am using a realtime website using PHP, jQuery and Node/Socket.io and all 3 communicate with each other.

Comment: Just for clarification, what I mean is Javascript is the language for node, but PHP can be used in conjunction with node.  You shouldnt be doing client stuff with PHP anyway.  PHP is a serverside language. :)

Comment: @PaulM @Alfred I never said you can't use them together, I said "`node.js` and `php` can but aren't advised to be used together".  The biggest benefit of using `node.js` is that you can use the same language client and server side.  You no longer have to learn/switch between two languages constantly.  For backwards support using php and `node.js` maje sense, but starting a new project (Geocine says "building a realtime app") with `node.js` and `php` is well overkill.

Comment: @Lime, yes I know you never said.  I read your response wrong and went into zealot mode.  Hence why I made the clarification afterwards.  But I will disagree with you.  Using PHP for serverside stuff should he need it, is not overkill.  Sure he says realtime, but I bet it wont all be realtime heh.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." Reference: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**General**

- [Node.js Digs Dirt - about Data-Intensive Real-Time Applications](http://video.nextconf.eu/video/1914374/nodejs-digs-dirt-about)

**Node.js**

- [How do I get started with NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-nodejs/5511507#5511507)

**socket.io**

- [Embracing all with Socket.io](http://nodetuts.com/tutorials/7-embracing-all-with-socketio.html)
- [Websockets everywhere with Socket.IO](http://howtonode.org/websockets-socketio)

**Redis**

- [Must read tutorial](http://simonwillison.net/static/2010/redis-tutorial/)
- [Data types intro](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro)
- also [command docs](http://redis.io/commands) are very handy