# How to execute a Node.js script on the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm beginning to learn web technologies and programming and I'm setting up my own local webserver. I have HTTPD, PHP, Python, MySQL all up and running on Windows. Now I want to add Node.js to the mix. I installed the Windows 64 bit installer. Now how do I begin? I have a basic Hello World script in a test.js file. But when I access this file in the browser it only displays as plain text. It's not executed. How to execute a Node.js script on the server?

Comment: `node /path/to/your/file.js`

Comment: Sorry for my newbie. Ok. It works. But how do I deploy it to a Web Hosting server online? I don't suppose I log into the server and type 'node file.js' every time I want the server to run

Comment: Currently you've to type in that command. Manually or through a service/tool/whatever like Jenkins. There are a lot of SaaS provider where you can automatically deploy and start your services in a GUI. Take a tour through Google.

Comment: I see. One more question. How about the port? I expect users to open my URL without specifing a designated port. Just www.domain.com i.e. How to run Node.js on a default port?

Comment: @Aardenon check my answer

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947195/start-with-node-js-as-a-complete-server-side-newbie

Comment: @Aardenon Since it would be a bit too much to answer all your questions inside of those comments I've just set up an answer with a brief summary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting a node script is pretty simple. Just use your command line or terminal and execute the following command.

```
node /path/to/your/file.js
```

Doing so you'll start your node script. If you're going to start a server it's pretty much the same. Just keep in mind to define a server in your node file and start it. A simple server using [express](http://expressjs.com/) could look like this (You can also use a fully node way, this is just a simple example using express. You may check google for how to set up a simple node http server).

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 4000;

app.listen(process.env.port || port);
```

As you can see the specified port is set to `4000`. You can simply adjust this by changing the value itself or passing in a node environment variable. To pass in an environment variable just start your server like this.

```
node port=3000 /path/to/your/file.js
```

This will finally pass the value of port to `process.env.port` which obviously will start your server on the port `3000`.

Comment: Ok. I got it up and running! Will need to do some more research on deploying it to an online web-hosting though in due time :-)

Answer (score 2):

you can use these packages to keep the file running so you won't have to  login to server every time :-

[forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever)
and you can just write :-

```
forever start app.js
```

[nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon)

```
nodemon app.js
```

[pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2)
which is very useful , as it will auto restart your app when it crash or any error happens

```
pm2 start app.js
```

Comment: The question says that they script only does "Hello, world". Your answer is skipping the bit where you write the JavaScript to create an HTTP server.

Comment: check the  comments blow his question , he asked about how he can keep the app running  on server

Answer (score 0):

Your run your file: `node server.js`

Then it starts.

There should be specified in code on which port you run your server. Then it is accessible for example at `http://localhost:3000/`

---

As Quentin noted, I was thinking about "creating web server". Of course, you can run javascript code with Node.js without server. Then skip the part abot localhost, just use `node test.js` in console.

Comment: The question says that they script only does "Hello, world". Your answer is skipping the bit where you write the JavaScript to create an HTTP server.

Comment: @Quentin - true, I fixed answer