# HTML5 Boilerplate build scripts doesn't replace script tags in index.html

Tags: javascript, ant, html5boilerplate

I am just getting started with the HTML5 boilerplate build script and I am having some problems. Basically all my scripts are minified and compressed as I would hope, but all of the  original `<script>` tags are left in the output `index.html`. What I need is for it to replace these tags with a reference to the minified js file. I thought this should happen by default. Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rolling my own build script with [rake](https://rubygems.org/gems/rake) and the [javascript closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/). It was pretty easy actually.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the code responsible for replacing is in the `build.xml` file target `-usemin` especially  [this code](https://github.com/h5bp/ant-build-script/blob/master/build.xml#L665-L670).

1. If it is so then it searches for comment region marked with `//-beg- concat_js` and `//-end- concat_js` as is described as must-have in the [quick start section](https://github.com/h5bp/ant-build-script#quick-start).
2. Also make sure that you have set the `file.root.script` property in the `project.properties` file to the script you really use (default value expects `main.js`)

Running `ant -debug >log.txt` helps me a lot.

You can find helpful answer by [searching through existing issues at GitHub](https://github.com/h5bp/ant-build-script/search?q=how-to-bypass-the-automatic-script-concatenation&type=Issues), especially the article https://github.com/h5bp/ant-build-script/wiki/How-to-bypass-the-automatic-script-concatenation seems to be roblarsen's final answer to script concatenation problems.

I ended up with my custom [Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js) build script that runs [wintersmith](https://github.com/jnordberg/wintersmith) and HTML5 Boilerplate build script, does some configuration of those tools and it works.