# Learning NodeJS

Tags: node.js

Really need a book recommendation for mastering node.js.

From this list...or ?

http://www.chapters.indigo.ca/home/search/?keywords=nodejs&pageSize=12

Comment: http://howtonode.org/  Lots of great stuff there.

Comment: SO is not a site for recommendations of pretty much any variety (language, book, library, etc.).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get started with Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js)

Answer (score 2):

I personally like http://www.nodebeginner.org/ as a foundation.

PeepCode Full Stack Node.js screencast https://peepcode.com/products/full-stack-nodejs-i helps to understand aspects of practical use.

Also Google for deploying Node.js applications to production as it is not as straightforward as with more traditional server side technologies on web and it can make an impact on your application strategy.