# there is tutorial for PURE node.js?

Tags: node.js

I was searching for node.js tutorials for pretty long..
I just got my book for node and I realized that before I learned something I had to use express.js module.

There is a tutorial or a book that teaches how to create pure node.js web applications,
without any node packaged modules (npm)?

Because firstly I want to learn pure node.js, and maybe then I will use some of the npm later.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not a duplicate of "How to get starte with Node.js", this question is about how to write a server using only core Node.js modules.

For example I have an express v4 server that now is marked as insecure and I should upgrade to express v5 which is alpha now..

My server is really simple, and I think it could be ported to pure Node.js, using only core moules.

I found this article really inherent and interesting: http://danialk.github.io/blog/2013/01/23/simple-node-server/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The official API documentation is the best and most up-to-date resource when it comes to pure node.js. For web applications see the HTTP API documentation at http://nodejs.org/api/http.html.

You could also check out previous questions like this, this seemed like a great answer: [How do I get started with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js).

Answer (score 3):

I'm personally a big fan of the [Smashing Node.js](http://smashingnode.com/) book. It starts off with some JavaScript stuff itself, then moves on to V8/Node JS, and from there moves on to tcp/http etc. It doesn't touch express until much later in the book. It also covers common db's used in the node world such as mongo, redis and MySql. Worth the money IMO.