# Stop Node from letting PHP file to be downloaded

Tags: php, node.js

I know PHP file doesn't get executed in node server, so it let the PHP file to be downloaded.

This is a huge security risk, isn't it? How to stop node from letting users download the php file?

Comment: As you correctly see, node.js does not execute PHP files... so what is it supposed to do with them? Why are you making PHP files accessible on a node.js webserver in the first place?

Comment: @migg Well tell my how to restrict the access? sorry i'm new to node!

Comment: Just don't mix your files.  No point in finding a technical solution when some simple project organization solves all your problems.

Comment: You have to provide more details for more detailed help. If you are new to node, [read read read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js)