# Simple svg charts on Server and Mobile

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, dc.js

I want to run a simple chart, say e.g bar chart both on a pc and mobile. They should look the same and should be svg based. I did some research and found may be d3.js with node.js is the way to go. Say I am ok with running node.js in the server side. How can use the same javascript code on both server and client side? The graph needs to be interactive, say when I have 2 simple graphs together, so the value I click on one graph is passed on to other graph. I am new to both javascript and node.js.

If the client is a pc with an advanced browser like chrome, I want the graph to be render the graph in the client, where as if the client is a mobile client android/iphone the server should should do the heavy lifting.

Any pointers to other charting library options, tutorials are also welcome.Thanks in advance.

(Note: It will be nice, if the library is open source and the licence is not restrictive and allows commercial usage. )

Answer (score 2):

`d3.js` is one of the best JavaScript libraries for data visualization. Take a look at `d3.js` [workshop](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/d3/workshop/) and [wiki tutorial](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials) for pointers on how to use d3.js

`node.js` is JavaScript-based web server framework. You have some good FAQ's about node.js on StackOverflow itself :

1. [How do I get started with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js)
2. [node.js beginner tutorials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600792/node-js-beginner-tutorials)

**Advance Usage**

Since both node and d3 are in JavaScript. You can use `d3.js` and `dc.js` from node itself. This allows you to do heavy compute/rendering on server, and send the graphics to client. You should attempt these only if you are familiar with both `node.js` and `d3.js`.

1. node package for [d3.js](https://npmjs.org/package/d3)
2. node package for [dc.js](https://npmjs.org/package/dc)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of highcharts for javascript charting. Very easy to use and powerful.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am looking for some thing with a less restrictive license which will allow commercial usage as well.