# Is there any online exercises on Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm new at Node.js and i need some practice on it, so is there any online exercises same as http://www.codecademy.com/  for node.js?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js  a little searching effort goes a long way

Comment: yes i saw this.... but i need some coding exercises not just reading tutorials.

Comment: @user2224801 A tutorial typically is a series of exercises. Are you just looking for one that's exercise-heavy? Less reading required?

Comment: Yes, i'd like to have some exercises rather than reading.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. I'm looking for a more exercise-heavy approach. For example, [algorithm](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/42sort/) tutorials are usually exercise-heavy. Textbooks on Node tend to be descriptive and exercise-free. [freeCodeCamp](http://freecodecamp.com) is pretty much a compilation of progressive projects, but I'm looking for smaller steps, just like [algorithm](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/42sort/) tutorials.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just *do* the tutorials as you read them.  Try setting up a webserver and serving a page that says "hello."  I'm  not sure you're going to find interactive exercises like codeacademy for something like nodejs.

Again I think your best bet is the previous SO question [How do I get started with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js)

Answer (score 10):

There is a node.js course at CodeSchool (the first lesson is free, $29/mo after): http://node.codeschool.com/