# Any up-to-date tutorials of Express 4.0 with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to learn Node.js and I've been using Lynda.com, the book Node.js in Action, and I've scoured the web trying to look for online tutorials for current versions of Express (Express ~4.2) with Node.js.

Almost everything I've seen has Express 3.4 and this has a lot of deprecated code. These have become more of a hindrance than a help.

Does anyone know any good videos or step-by-step tutorials with updated versions of Express? Thank you.

EDIT: The answer given below from Waldo was perfect, and anyone having the same issues I had should use the links given by Waldo.

I have found additional information for those wanting more help learning Express 4.0 or navigating from Express 3.0 to 4.0.

[A GitHub guide to code changed from 3.0 to 4.0](https://github.com/strongloop/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x#changed)

[Create server-side MVC apps with Node.js and Express](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QseHOX-5nJQ)

[Creating RESTful APIs with Express 4](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-restful-apis-express-4/)  (Thank you Romo!)

[Lynda.Com has one updated tutorial,](http://www.lynda.com/Expressjs-tutorials/Building-Website-Nodejs-Expressjs/163094-2.html) but they also have at least two more with deprecated code.

Comment: Can [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-restful-apis-express-4/) tutorial help you ? :/

Comment: Looks promising, thank you! I'll add that to my question post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156736/is-there-any-online-exercises-on-node-js

Comment: That doesn't answer the question or help in the slightest. The forum post is only related in that in involves Node.js. It doesn't deal specifically with the newest version of Express like my question does.

Besides, for a comprehensive guide to Node.js this is a  much better forum question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/skeleton_website is a very good tutorial!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are some tutorials which I find helpful for Express 4.0

- [Build a RESTful API -
  Scotch.io](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4)
- [Learn to use Express 4.0 Router -
  Scotch.io](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/learn-to-use-the-new-router-in-expressjs-4)
- [Express 4.0 vs 3.0 -
  Scotch.io](http://scotch.io/bar-talk/expressjs-4-0-new-features-and-upgrading-from-3-0)
- [Easy Node.js Authentication for Express 3.0 -
  Scotch.io](http://scotch.io/series/easy-node-authentication) and [Its
  upgrade for Express
  4.0](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/upgrading-our-easy-node-authentication-series-to-expressjs-4-0)
  ***(One the best tutorials for authentication in Node.js : )***
- [Authenticating Node.js with Passport -
  TutsPlus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/authenticating-nodejs-applications-with-passport--cms-21619)
  *(Very similar to the previous one)*
- [Building a RESTful API With Passport -
  BeerLocker](http://scottksmith.com/blog/2014/05/29/beer-locker-building-a-restful-api-with-node-passport/)
- [Expressworks - Nodeschool.io](http://nodeschool.io/#expressworks)
  ***(Good interactive tutorials)***
- [Learn All The Nodes](http://www.learnallthenodes.com/) *(A good
  video series tutorial about building an entire app, updated for
  Express 4.0 since Episode 20)*

Hope that helps

Comment: If this information doesn't help me, nothing will. Thanks a million!!!

Comment: the links don't work :(

Answer (score 4):

Please find Series of Express 4 tutorial covering from Express configuration to deployment :

http://codeforgeek.com/2014/10/express-complete-tutorial-part-1/
http://codeforgeek.com/2014/10/express-complete-tutorial-part-2/

You can find more 3 in the post.

Hope it helps !

Comment: I've already got an answer, but thank you anyways! If anything, this will help others who are having a similar issue!

Comment: This is awesome! I just listed you on http://hackr.io/tutorials/express-js as well.

Comment: Thanks +Gaurav for listing