# How do I get started with Node.js

Tags: node.js

I want to implement video conference on my project,i have used it with third party database, now i want to use node.js for that purpose.
Are there any good resources to get started with Node.JS? Any good tutorials, blogs or books?
I have visited its official website http://nodejs.org/, but I didn't think the documentation they have is a good starting point.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see [this link](http://jsbooks.revolunet.com/), there are a lot of valuable javascript-books  for free. you should definitly read the "mastering nodejs" book from TJ Holowaychuk. if you are kind of firm with javascript you can read that easily. if not, read "node beginner" first.

then you should definitly use the npm-registry and use existing modules. you can browse the registry, and take a look at some repositories, and learn from them.

regarding your application, take a look at the [webrtc modules](https://npmjs.org/search?q=webrtc)

Comment: +1 stellar book collection, man. out-of-this-world ebooks, dude. cosmic understandings inside, bru.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://javascriptissexy.com/learn-node-js-completely-and-with-confidence/) is a complete guide as to How to go about learning nodejs. It was very helpful. Other than that You can use this [book](http://www.manning.com/cantelon/) also. Its recommended by Express Framework, so it should be quite good(I have read it and found it good).

In the guide mentioned above there are many tutorials and videos mentioned also which you should go through. Have a look. I hope you find it useful