# node.js suitable for small Projects

Tags: node.js

Our Customers often have Requirements for some small WebProjects, to integrate in our EnterpriseEnviroment. Currently I create those Apps with ASP.NET WebForms or MVC but this Technology often feels a little bit to heavy for this kind of purpose.

I really don´t know much about node.js, only that it scales very well and is good for having a lot of concurrent connections.

So I've asked myself:

- Is node.js suitable for small Projects ?
- Do I have any advantages for a small Project?
- Am I right that it´s more lightweight than ASP.NET WebForms/MVC
- How is the node.js support for WindowsServer? Or should I setup a LinuxBox for it?
- How is the Database support in node.js ?
- Does it support direct DB-Connection to MSSQL-Server?
- Or is it better to get my Data from a WebService?

I know that node.js is only server-side and you can´t really compare it 100% with something like ASP.NET WebForms/MVC

Comment: I really don´t understand why my Question get´s downvoted and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js) over 1000 upvotes, I think how to get started is also a very broad Question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is node.js suitable for small Projects ?

Yes.

> Do I have any advantages for a small Project?

Very lightweight, very modular, easy to install.

> Am I right that it´s more lightweight than ASP.NET WebForms/MVC

Enormously so.

> How is the node.js support for WindowsServer? Or should I setup a LinuxBox for it?

It works OK on Windows.  It would probably suffice to install a Linux shell.

> How is the Database support in node.js ?

Beautiful.

> Does it support direct DB-Connection to MSSQL-Server?

Yes, I believe it does.

> Or is it better to get my Data from a WebService?

"Better" is kind of vague, but for a very small project, simplicity is generally the key, so no.