# editor/ide for node.js development

Tags: node.js, ide, editor

Which IDE or Editor do you use for node.js Development on Windows or Linux?

Currently I only know 2 IDE-Extensions:

- [Node.js Tools for Visual Studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/885a8a68-e38b-4e6a-b96d-083d5572b645) (which I use and which of course is only available for Windows)
- [Nodeclipse](http://www.nodeclipse.org/enide/)

both are in a pretty early Development-Stage, so I wondered are there  more Alternatives out there? Or is it common to use an Editor with Syntax-Highlighting for Node.js Development?

Comment: You can use a text-editor for [tag:node.js] development. I personally use `Sublime Text`.

Comment: notepadd++, by far the best.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get started with Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Webstorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) from Jetbrains is very good and allows debugging with node.js.

Comment: looks promising :) and € 44 is not that much, will try the trial version.

Comment: I know this Question don´t really has an correct answer but I picked this one because I didn´t know about Webstorm, and it is a very nice IDE for node.js development!

Answer (score 2):

Every IDE which supports JavaScript highlighting will do the job. I personally use Sublime Text. While you work on node apps you have to monitor their output. I just place the console in my second monitor, but if you use only one you may need to setup a build process.