# A few questions about node.js

Tags: node.js

Am I right in thinking that node.js is a "total" development platform, in much the same way as asp.NET, PHP and even classic ASP are?

There seems to be a lot of excitement about node.js which makes me a little nervious about it being yet another "flash in the pan" type technology that will fade away?

If I was going to go about learning node.js have you got any tips how I might start out, without frying my brian?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get started with Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js)

Comment: As for question #1, you can do mostly anything. As for "question" #2, how's anyone going to answer that?

Comment: Yeah sorry. Question 2 is quite subjective. Just wanted to get a general feel about the technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said DmitryR, node.js is a framework of Javascript.
It is also based on the V8 engine of Chrome.
It is server side based, but can be used for non-internet application too (I m develloping one right now).

What is your goal in learning Node.js?

> Create a website

Wrong choice

> Create a web app (like a chat)

Good choice

> Learning a new language ''for fun''

Good choice too, Node.js is asynchronous and quite easy to learn, even with obscure docs, and can be used for a lot of things. It is also a script, so it don t require to be compiled, but you better be on non-windows os, since node.js for windows can be a pain for devellopement.

If you want tips about where to start, you d better start by understanding asynchronous programming, it s the only "hard" part of this language.

Comment: #DrakaSAN Thanks for the feedback. I think you've hit the nail on the head. I think the thing that attracted me was the fact it's based on javascript. But just wanted to get a feel as to what it was really useful for. From my point of view my goal would really be learning a new language for fun. So I might well go for it. Although, yeah, I'm on windows :) Thanks again.

Comment: You can accept the answer if you have all you wanted to hear ; ). If you ve already done some javascript, it s all for the better, since you ll not start learning from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Node.js is not a platform for common applications like blogs, etc.
It's for fast async apps like chats, relays, etc

It can be compared to [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) framework (Python), [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) framework (Python) or [eventmachine](http://rubyeventmachine.com/) framework (Ruby).

Comment: So it's quite specific the sort of uses it's suited to. IE> You wouldn't use it for day to day quite static website development for example.

Answer (score 1):

There are some interactive ways to learn node.js like:

- [nodeschool](http://nodeschool.io/)
- [node.codeschool](http://node.codeschool.com/levels/1/challenges/1)

You can give them a try.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check them out.