# How to create and run a file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, createjs

I installed node.js new version and I checked in command prompt by using node-v and npm-v
I want to know how create and run that file.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js

Comment: You will find countless guides on this if you use google

Answer (score 1):

Create the file hello.js in the root directory of your project, and fill it with the following code:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

First, execute your script with Node.js in the command prompt:

```
node hello.js
```

open your browser and point it at `http://localhost:8888/` . You will see a message "Hello World" .

Answer (score 0):

You can start the Node.js process like this:

```
% node example.js
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/
```

Comment: C:\Neetesh\Node.js\node_modules\npm\test\hello.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { consol.log('Hell
                                                              ^
ReferenceError: consol is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Neetesh\Node.js\node_modules\npm\test\hello.js:1:6
3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12) at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:901:3

Comment: C:\Neetesh\Node.js\node_modules\npm\test\hello.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { consol.log('Hell
                                                            ReferenceError: consol is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Neetesh\Node.js\node_modules\npm\test\hello.js:1:6
3)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10) at node.js:901:3 i am getting this error while running the file

Comment: I would suggest finding and fixing the typo-ed `console.log`. That should immediately fix that error message.