# Node.js tutorial web server not responding

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was viewing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js) post while trying to get started Node.js, and I started working with [this guide](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/node-js-for-beginners/) to learn the basics.

The code for my server is :

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    request.on('end', function() {
        response.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'
        });
        response.end('Hello HTTP!');
    });
}).listen(8080);
```

When I go to localhost:8080 (per the guide), I get a 'No Data Received' error. I've seen some pages that say https:// are required, but that returns a 'SSL Connection Error'. I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: did you run the file as "node filename.js" ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem in your code is that "end" event is never fired because you are using Stream2 `request` stream as if it's Stream1. Read migration tutorial - http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/12/20/streams2/

To convert it to "old mode stream behavior" you can add "data" event handler or '.resume()' call:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    request.resume();
    request.on('end', function() {

        response.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'
        });
        response.end('Hello HTTP!');
    });
}).listen(8080);
```

If your example is http GET handler you already have all headers and don't need to wait for body:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'
  });
  response.end('Hello HTTP!');
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Awesome. Sorry I didn't notice the date between the tutorial I was using and now, or that the tutorial didn't switch to v10 streams.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't wait for a request-end event. Straight from http://nodejs.org/ with slight modifications:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: It has, because request is a stream.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. Updated answer, although yours is the better one, anyways.