# how do i read the /usr/local/bin/node binary?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to learn node and want to figure out what the 'node' command actually does?

Is there a way to read the 'node' command or interpret it? Where would I start in their API, http://nodejs.org/api/ to figure out what node is and does?

Comment: the `node` command is the javascript engine and runtime.  There's sourcecode available on the nodejs.org site, but if you're interested in "learning" node then you're talking about learning how to write serverside javascript.  There's a lot of tutorials on that.

Comment: If you want to learn node.js check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js and www.nodebeginner.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ is here: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/node.cc#L3257 and the JavaScript is here: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/node.js