# node.js command prompt not initialised as expected

Tags: node.js, installation

I installed the .msi file from nodejs website and installed it.
Now, when I run nodejs.exe, I do get a command prompt, but it shows a blinking `>` by default, instead of `C:/>`

It looks somewhat like this:
[image]

What to do?

Comment: What do you mean by "frozen"? Have you tried typing something into the node prompt? Try `1+1` then press **enter**.

Comment: Yup! It returned 2. Actually, it's not "frozen". Just that I was trying out some basic tuts, and I couldn't get the `C:/>`. Question edited, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called the [REPL](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html).  You can enter statements for Node to execute and get realtime feedback. Ctrl+C twice will get you back to the command prompt.

I recommend checking out the answers to [How do I get started with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js) for learning more about Node.js and how it works.  Typically you provide a file with your Javascript for Node to execute:

`node app.js`

or you can leave the `.js` off:

`node app`

Comment: In the tutorial I saw, they had a command prompt where instead of the `>` they had `C:/>`. How can I get that?

Comment: Typically you just run Node.js from the command prompt (C:\>) providing it the name of the javascript file you want to run.  It sounds like you just need to run the Command Prompt (Win+x, Command Prompt) and then you'll be able to follow the tutorial from there.