# How to develop a simple webpage for a CLI Node.js script

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, frontend

I have a Node.js script running locally through command line (I haven't developed it so not very familiar with the code) which takes an email address as a parameter and looks up some data and spits out results in a command line table.

I wanted to make a "front-end" for this, like a simple local Webpage where I could punch in an email address and see the response right on the browser itself.

I am not very familiar where to get started without complicating this into a bigger problem than it is. Any guidance would be very helpful here. I haven't really done any web development using Node or JS before but I am familiar with basic web development (and willing to learn) new ways of doing things.

If I can provide any additional information please let me know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The most prominent framework for developing node apps is `express.js`.  You can't go wrong if you invest some effort into learning express.  It will help you with routing and templates, and can generate a skeleton application for you.  Read through the guide, and learn:

http://expressjs.com/guide.html

Also you may study the answer to the most popular node question on this site:

[How do I get started with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js/5511507#5511507)