# Retrieving tweets and displaying them on web

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

```
var Twit = require('twit');
var client = new Twit({
consumer_key: 'xxx',
consumer_secret: 'xxx',
access_token: 'xxx',
access_token_secret: 'xxx'
});

client.get('search/tweets', { q: 'screenName' since:2011-11-11', count: 100 },
        function(err, data, response) {
            for (var indx in data.statuses) {
                var tweet= data.statuses[indx];
                console.log('on: ' + tweet.created_at + ' : @' + tweet.user.screen_name + ' : ' + tweet.text+'\n\n');
            }

        })
```

I have the code above to display tweets according to "screenName" to console, but I want to display them on an HTML page. How do I do that? Will I have to use JQuery?Can someone explain in detail?

Your help will be appreciated!

Comment: use `response.send(data)`
to send data to view and then use the same for loop(in ur code) to print it where ever you want on webpage.

Comment: I believe this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617468/node-js-generate-html) would help you.

Answer (score 0):

First 'response.send(data)' to send data to the templating engine and then you don't have to use jQuery to display at HTML simply. You can do this by

```
client.get('search/tweets', { q: 'screenName' since:2011-11-11', count: 100 },
    function(err, data, response) {
        for (var indx in data.statuses) {
            var tweet= data.statuses[indx];
            console.log('on: ' + tweet.created_at + ' : @' + tweet.user.screen_name + ' : ' + tweet.text+'\n\n');
            response.send(data);
        }

    })
```

then in your template JavaScript simply write

```
            //after received data in request
            for (var indx in res.data.statuses) {
                var tweet= data.statuses[indx];
                document.write('on: ' + tweet.created_at + ' : @' + tweet.user.screen_name + ' : ' + tweet.text+'\n\n');
            }
```

Hope it helps.