# How to manipulate code in a html file stored at server side using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, react-fullstack

I am working on a project in which I have a folder on the server-side. The folder contains HTML, CSS and JS files that can be used to deploy a static site. I need to manipulate the code in the HTML file based on the data entered by the user on client-side and after the HTML, CSS, js files have been modified the user can download it in .zip format.

The problem I am facing are:

1. How to edit code wherever I want in the files from the copy of the folder I created. To be precise If I want a `<P> section </P>` at a specific place in the HTML code, how do I do it? Can node.js be used for this? Would I need the code line number where I want to insert a new snippet?
2. How to send user data like images to the server-side? For the data in the text format, would the JSON format work? Is node.js the right choice for this project?

[image: Schema of the project]

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617468/node-js-generate-html).

Comment: @Matt I will look into this. Thank you