# how get return value (of mongoose query output within model.exports ) to a calling module

Tags: node.js, mongoose

For a project, I am working to get return value to main application module post validation of user and password from a mongoDB using mongoose. I am able to printout result post "User.findOne" using console.log (commented in code) but fail to pass this result to main module "app.js". I am getting "undefined" as output or initialised value of "result" if do in the User.js module.

**Need help to know how to get return value (of "result" in below code) from User.js to app.js.**

I am not looking for return this value  using "res.send" as web response. which i found mostly while exploring google for the issue.

Thanks.

app.js

```
var user = require ('./User');
console.log(user.authentication("user","pass"));
```

User.js

```
var User = require('./models/Mongoose');

exports.authentication = function(user, pass){
  var query = {uid: user};
  var result;
  //var result = "None";
  User.findOne(query, function(err,obj) {
    if (err) {
      result = "error: find method";
    } else {
      if (obj != null) {
        if ( pass == obj.password) {
          //console.log("success: authorisation successful");
          result = "authentication successful";
        } else {
          //console.log("error: password incorrect");
          result = "authentication failed";
        }
      } else {
        result = "error: absent user";
      }
    }
  });
  return result;
};
```

Output of app.js:

```
undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You return result before User.findOne has any opportunity to give you something. Instead you should add a callback function to authentication method e.g.

```
exports.auth = function(user, pass, callback){
  User.findOne(...., function(err, user){
   var result = !!user;
   callback(err, result);
 });
}
```

Anyway, you should get used to asynchronous code to feel comfortable working with node. These tutorials are likely to help you: [How do I get started with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js)

Comment: Where is callback defined?  The router?

Comment: @michaelAdam Actually, it doesn't matter. You provide the callback yourself wherever you use `exports.auth`. It's nothing more than just a simple function that follows convention of expecting possible error as the first argument and result as the rest args.