# Web Developer want to learn Node.js

Tags: node.js, web-development-server

I have 2 years of experience in Web-Development  having knowledge of Struts and JSF ,and now i want to learn Node.js...is it worthy to learn it?is it going to give any benefit to me  in my career path.
Thanks
Please suggest

Comment: The worthiness of any technology is extremely subjective. But from any decent web developer I would expect to have some experience in two or more of `node.js`, `ruby`, `python` and `java`. Is it worth to know stuff beyond Java when being web developer? Imperative I would say

Comment: In my opinion it is worth the effort, It is enjoyable technology. the benefits in your career path is something you have to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js) you have some other stack overflow post that explain well how to learn Node.js.

To me Node.js is a great language and it worth it to be learned. [Here](http://webdevs.co/4-reasons-why-node-js-is-the-future/) you have a great article who explain well why Node.js is worthwhile.