# Simple example yii-node-socket

Tags: node.js, yii, yii-extensions

My final goal : integrate this app https://github.com/bobrik/pupergrep (tail -f log) in my Yii project with this extension : https://github.com/oncesk/yii-node-socket.

i have installed the pupergrep project without problem, and my Yii project work.But 
i'm totaly new with node.js, so i need for start a simple example with the Yii extension https://github.com/oncesk/yii-node-socket, i don't understand exactly where i need ta place my code server/client, how to name my js file server, how to receive (not send) data from server to my client.

Anybody have try the Yii extension yii-node-socket ?

Comment: Please note: the yii-node-socket has no LICENSE what means you shouldn't use this without asking the owner. Maybe you ask him to add a LICENSE file and if he would share this code by MIT or Apache2 License.

Comment: To start with node.js http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js is a very good collection ! My favorite is https://github.com/rvagg/learnyounode