# How does this npm build work?

Tags: node.js, npm, swagger

https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-converter

I see this code:

```
var convert = require('swagger-converter');
var fs = require('fs');
var resourceListing = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('/path/to/petstore/index.json').toString());
var apiDeclarations = [ JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('/path/to/petstore/pet.json').toString()),
JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('/path/to/petstore/user.json').toString()),
JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('/path/to/petstore/store.json').toString())
];

var swagger2Document = convert(resourceListing, apiDeclarations);

console.log(JSON.stringify(swagger2Document, null, 2));
```

I'm confsued as to what exactly I'm supposed to do here to run this?  Do I start a node http server?

Comment: Probably would be best to ask in that project issues.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js

Comment: Just save that into a `something.js` file and run `node something.js` and your should see you new document in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the file you pasted, just save the code into a file like `script.js`. Then from the command line (with [node](http://nodejs.org) installed) run `node script.js`. That will run the file. Here's a breakdown of what it's doing:

```
var convert = require('swagger-converter');
```

This line gets reference to the swagger-converter module that you linked to. That module is designed to allow you to convert swagger documents into [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

This line gets reference to the node built-in filesystem module (fs for short). It provides an API for interacting with the filesystem on your machine when the script is running.

```
var resourceListing = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('/path/to/petstore/index.json').toString());
```

This line could be broken down to:

```
var indexContent = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/petstore/index.json');
JSON.parse(indexContent.toString());
```

`readFileSync` returns the contents of the `index.json` file as a buffer object, which is easily turned into a simple string with the call to `.toString()`. Then they pass it to `JSON.parse` which parses the string and turns it into a simple JavaScript object.

> Fun Fact: They could have skipped those steps with a simple `var resourceListing = require('/path/to/petstore/index.json');`. Node knows how to read JSON files and automatically turn them into JavaScript objects. You need only pass the path to `require`.

```
var apiDeclarations = [ JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('/path/to/petstore/pet.json').toString()),
JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('/path/to/petstore/user.json').toString()),
JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('/path/to/petstore/store.json').toString())
];
```

This bit of code does the same thing as the `resourceListing` except it creates an array of three JavaScript objects based on those JSON files. They also could have used `require` here to save a bit of work.

Then finally they use the converter to do the conversion and then they log that data to the terminal where your script is running.

```
var swagger2Document = convert(resourceListing, apiDeclarations);
console.log(JSON.stringify(swagger2Document, null, 2));
```

`JSON.stringify` is the opposite of `JSON.parse`. `stringify` turns a JavaScript object into a JSON string whereas `parse` turns a JSON string into a JavaScript object.