# ReferenceError: Require is not defined (Webstorm)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm, mean-stack

Trying to do something incredibly basic, but running into a snag.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/jetbrains');

var Product = mongoose.model('Product', {name: String});

var product = new Product({name: "WebStorm"});

product.save(function(err) {
    if(err){
        console.log('failed');
    }else{
        console.log('saved');
    }
});
```

Continually getting ReferenceError: require is not defined at [file path].

I'm doing this in Webstorm 10. Trying to folow this tutorial on MEAN development in Webstorm. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JnMvok0Yks8

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably trying to run the above code in the Browser. It's supposed to run on the Node server. Node automatically defines the `require` function so you would never have this problem.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js) for good "getting started" material.

**EDIT**

That's really strange. WebStorm is definitely running Node.js if it's running on the Terminal. Can you please put a break point on the first line, debug the file and inspect the `require` function?

[image]

Comment: Hm. Trying to figure out how to do this in Webstorm. When I hit "Run" it goes to terminal but you might be right in that its not calling up Node.

Comment: Got it. Needed to set Node.js as a run configuration. Thanks Andrepena :-)

Comment: I'm glad you got that fixed