# Node.js how to install learnyounode?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to start learning Node.js, in the main site there was a link to: [nodeschool](http://nodeschool.io/#workshoppers)

And there was a link to: [learnyounode](https://github.com/workshopper/learnyounode)

I read the README file, but I dont understand what I should download from there, also I dont get where to put the files that I should download

Because I try to run with nothing the command they said there:

```
sudo npm install learnyounode -g
```

And I just get an error: *Unexpected Identifer*

Also, where do I need to put the js files that I create before I run them ?

Please help, thanks

I did a search before I wrote, and I found those Que's [How do I get started with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js) , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274167/how-to-start-node-js
but no one talked about learnyounode

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to run that command in the Node console. You should run it in the shell instead.

Comment: @Juhana Where is the shell? and what i sould download?

Comment: You'll have to tell which operating system you're using. Google for "how to use npm" for instructions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Learnyounode is just like any other NPM package for that matter. I think what you are trying should work, but for some reason, last time I tried I experienced that problem too, and by taking out the "sudo" it got installed. Try using `npm install learnyounode -g` in the shell. After installing it, its started via the command line.

You can place the js files you create wherever you want, but you will need to specify the route when entering a solution.

Comment: You right, its realy dont recognize the sudo command... now its work on Command Line like @Juhana said.