# how to run node.js on windows with apache server installed in?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache

I'm a node.js begginer . Let's say I have an apache server(XAAMP) and node.js installed in `C:\Program Files\nodejs\nodejs.exe` on windows 7.

How can I run node.js in my apache server to simulate my code?

I mean, I know how to write node.js code but what I don't know how it's work on my server?

Comment: Apache has nothing to do with it. You create the server in your node file and then start it up with `node path/to/your/file`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js

Comment: @m59 ok but how to put it on public  ?

Comment: @mahmoudnezarsarhan You have to write the code. See a hello world server example. `http.createServer(function(req, res) { res.end('Hello world!'); }).listen(8080);` Then start it up: `node that-file.js`. And then visit `localhost:8080`. As simple as that.

Comment: @m59 I'm so sorry for this stupid questions but there are no one to ask but you 
ok say I made server like yours in the comment how people reach it ?

Comment: people reach it by click to link http://yourserver:8080/ :)

Comment: maybe you want setup apache virtual host to proxy to your node.js app?

Comment: Great question.. No good answers so far. Let me re-phrase your question for you. `I want to use Node JS to handle serverside queries under Apache (and other IIS's) on Windows 7` - Is that even possible? Everywhere I look (inc below answers) says Use Node as a SERVER. That is probably the last thing I (or anyone?) would ever want to do on this planet. I have never heard of a Node being the front end entry point on a www server or a serious IIS. Does it even do encryption? What's the point? An intranet experiment? As a test environment?(not much of a test if it can't be replicated real world).

Answer (score 1):

Apache server don't need for Node.js.

For create your own Node.js server:

1. [Download](https://nodejs.org/download/) and install Node.js
2. Create file `hello.js`:

   ```
   var http = require("http");
   var server = http.createServer().listen(3000); // beter way for create
   server.on("request", function(req, res){
     res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
     // for view at page http://localhost:3000
     res.write("Hello world");
     res.end();
   });
   server.on("listening", function(){
     // for view in console
     console.log("Listen: 3000...");
   });
   ```
3. In terminal go to dir where file `hello.js` and type:

   ```
   node hello.js
   ```
4. Open your browser and point it at http://localhost:3000/. This should display a web page that says:

   ```
   Hello world
   ```

[A basic HTTP server](http://www.nodebeginner.org/#building-the-application-stack)

[Node.js Manual & Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you like to work with a replacement for XAAMP you should finally take a look at [MEAN.io](http://mean.io/).

At [NpmJS.org](https://www.npmjs.com) you will find different solutions for most of your needs.

and like Reagan Gallant commented you should take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js) famous stackoverflow post (if you need ideas).

NodeSchool indeed is a good entry point for your fist steps. After that npmjs will make sense and finally you will love Mean.io

Answer (score 0):

You just make it use a different port than Apache is using (for example port 3000 which is the default for express-js and others) -- that is assuming that you don't need the two to work together.

If you *do* need them to work together, you add a forwarding module to Apache and configure the forwarding in Apache of certain URL to go to your local port for node-js