# How I can start with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, nodeclipse

I must start with node.js and I use Nodeclipse to write my code. What do you think abount nodeclipse, it is a good IDE or not?
In the future, I must create a plugin. I read some documents abount "how write a node.js plugin". Does anyone know how I can create plugin with nodeclipse?

Comment: "What do you **think**" is a good magnet for "primarily opinion-based" closing reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write the code, not the IDE, so it doesn't matter. You can use nodeclipse, notepad or piece of chalk and the road to write a code.

You can learn all the basics of NPM in official [Getting Started guide](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/what-is-npm) (also how to create your own module and publish it using node package manager).

To learn Node.js basics follow this answer, there are tons of links to some tutorials and courses: [[stackoverflow] How do I get started with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js)