# Enide Studio 2015 on OSX - trying to debug

Tags: node.js, nodeclipse

I've been doing command line development of node.js on my Mac OSX El Capitan machine for a bit but wanted to try an IDE.  I loaded Eclipse Mars and added the Enide Studio 2015 from the marketplace.

Created both a example project and an express generator project but I can't seem to get them to run in either the debugger mode or run mode.

When I run debugger mode, it seem to run and shows in the console that it is running but when I go to http://localhost:5858/ I get a browser that only shows:

> Type: connect
>
> V8-Version: 4.6.85.28
>
> Protocol-Version: 1
>
> Embedding-Host: node v5.0.0
>
> Content-Length: 0

Any ideas?

Comment: When I try to use the run configuration, it terminates right away with  "  <terminated, exit value: 0>Node.js Process "

Comment: Here is a video cast of the problem https://youtu.be/ZS5fdY-u1EU

Comment: This is not IDE related. Compare when running from command line.

Comment: It runs fine from the command line.  When I run "# npm start" it works.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439920/how-i-can-start-with-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

In package.json what script is execute for `start` ?

Then right-click that script.js 
and <kbd>Run as -> Node application</kbd>
or <kbd>Debug as -> Node application</kbd>

`npm` does not have parameters to launch in debug mode