# what are the languages and frameworks I need to know before starting with Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to Node.JS. I actually want to know about the pre-requisites for learning Node.JS. I've started some online courses but still if I'm confused with the minimum knowledge I already have about this. Kindly Help me out.

Comment: Your question is too broad as is since it is asking for recommendations or tutorials. Node.js is Javascript, so syntax is the only prerequisite. After that, just learn the Node API and how to use it or search for what you need.

Comment: @cricket_007 No need for HTML, CSS, nor jQuery. Node.js is not a web framework.

Comment: @Martin - forgot that people use it for more than that. Edited.

Comment: You should have an idea about javascript, and also html, css you can check here a simple nodejs + express sample http://wiki.workassis.com/installing-express-with-nodejs/ expess is nodejs web frameworks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only pre-requisite is JavaScript .
You don't need to be an expert with a lot of programming experience but you should know the basics .

Answer (score 1):

Qualifications for learning something  is only the deep desire to learn, things which help you in case of node js are **SOLID** foundation of **javascript** first and  some advance concepts of JavaScript  before starting so can understand how things are working.

- Callbacks
- Asynchronous programming model
- Function and Objects in JavaScript
- Design pattern
- Event
- Web protocols especially HTTP

[**how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js)

Comment: Thank you. I've done some good JS tutorials on youtube, udemy and codecademy. I guess that helps.