# problems with node.js code for getting a server ip to connect to

Tags: node.js

I'm developing a node.js application to get an ip address from a variable located in the cloud. Later I want to use it to establish a TCP/IP connection with a server. This is the code I'm using:

```
...
var settingsip;
photon.get("ipAddress", function(response) {
    settingsip = response.result;
    console.log("Photon IP is:", settingsip);
  });

console.log("Photon IP2 is:", settingsip);
...
```

But the output which I'm obtaining is:

```
Photon IP2 is: undefined
Photon IP is: 10.230.89.118
```

Which is the problem for not getting the right value of settingsip when printing it as IP2?

Comment: welcome to javascript :)

Comment: You'll need to read more on the async nature of Node.  The problem here is that console.log runs before your photon.get.  Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js/5511507#5511507

Comment: Did you not find it odd that ip2 logged first?