# Node.JS Working Techniques

Tags: node.js

I am very curious about how node.js works. I have downloaded node.js but I have no idea how to use it. Does node.js work with XAMPP and MYSQL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js here's a comprehensive list of NodeJS tutorials, documentations, guides, etc.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you're asking. Node.js is just a runtime environment, it's up to you to do something with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js is itslf act as the XAMPP server,Its a platform not the language. You have to write code in JS and run that code on NOde server.
You can can use MYSQL,MongoDB, etc.. with node code as a DB.

Before jumping to Node.js try basic JS scripting and learn what is missing in normal JS then get your hands dirty with Node.js

Start with learning : non blocking IO model, event loop and higer odder functions.

watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) for better understanding.

Best of luck!
Keep posting Questions :)

Comment: Will you be able to guide me through node.js?

Comment: Sure!
IM me or mail down your issues at vaibhavjain882@gmail.com