# Installed Node.js and Sublime Text But Keep Getting Errors

Tags: node.js

I'm a beginner at trying to learn web development. I currently downloaded node from the [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/) website and also downloaded Sublime Text 3 from the website as well.

My code for sublime is as follows:

```
$ node
console.log("Who's you're daddy?");
```

When I try to run it on node.js I get an error that says:

> "Syntax Error, Unexpected Identifier."

This is literally step one and I'm already messing up. How have I set this up wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From What you are trying to do seems like you want to print "Some String" in the console using nodejs.

In nodejs you can create a javascript logic first and then you can execute that logic using node.

- Create a file somefile.js
- Write following code in the file:

  `console.log('Who's your daddy?');`
- In terminal and execute:

  `node /location/of/the/file/somefile.js`

It should print **'Who's your daddy?'** in the console.

To learn more about nodejs and to get started you can refer to [How do I get started with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js)