# migrate python code to NodeJS

Tags: python, node.js

I am a beginner in NodeJS. I have worked on some scripts in python which does some calculation on two csvs. Is there a easy way to migrate a python script to NodeJS? I don't know whether its a right way to do it. But I wanted to know is there any way for for it.

Any suggestions will be encouragable.

Comment: Please show the python code so we can better assist you.

Comment: Hello, now are you talking about actually transferring the code from Python to Javascript? OR are you talking about just running the Python scripts in your Node server, and then returning the data?

Comment: Thank you @MichaelJones for the reply. I was trying to know is there a way where we can convert the code. But like everyone said here, I think its a best way to start doing it actually. Thanks for the help. I will start learning NodeJS and then ask questions if I have any.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to convert the code to javascript there are tools available like [transcrypt](http://www.transcrypt.org/) which converts the python code to javascript.

Comment: Thank you @v.coder. I will try this if I find any difficulty in learning to code in NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple way :** understand your code and rewrite it in *node.js* format.

If you're a beginner in *node.js*, it's a good exercise to understand how *node.js* works.

I recommand you this post which regroup a lot of ressources to begin *node.js* : [How do I get started with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js)

**EDIT :** you can also execute your *Python* script with a *node.js* process, and use the result in *node.js*.

**Documentation :** https://nodejs.org/api/process.html

Comment: Thank you @F.kauder for leading me with so many documentation. I will start reading them and try to code.