# Where is the project folder for node.js app on digital ocean

Tags: node.js

I have just spun up a Digital Ocean Single Click App for node.js. I connected via SSH and installed npm. What directory do I run `npm init` in to start coding my new app?

My question is not:

> What are some good resources for getting started with node.

My questions is:

> Where do I run npm init.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get started with Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

After connecting to the server via SSH, go into the `var` folder and create a `www` folder. Then go into the `www` folder and create a `project` folder (name the folder with your project name). Inside that `project` folder, run `npm init` to initialize the project and then start coding.