# npm errors while attempting to use barcode scanner

Tags: react-native, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to use a barcode reader, because I really need it for my app, but I'm unable to start any projects that I've found.

For example, https://github.com/ideacreation/react-native-barcodescanner. Which command should I use to start this?

```
$ cd /c/Users/Me/Desktop/react-native-barcodescanner-master 
$ npm i
$ npm i --save react-native-barcodescanner
npm ERR! Windows_NT6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "--save" "react-native-barcodescanner"
npm ERR! node v6.11.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ENOSELF
npm ERR! Refusing to install react-native-barcodescanner as a dependency of itself
$ npm start npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600 npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.11.3 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! missing script: start
```

Comment: Is it your first time to use node / npm codes? If so, you should learn about node project. If not, please post your package.json.

Comment: You can able to identify what went wrong in the file  npm-debug.log it will be located C:\Users\Me\Desktop\react-native-barcodescanner-master\npm-debug.log  READ it

Comment: Related link for learning node.js [How do I get started with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

This library is deprecated with react-native v0.44, you should use [react-native-camera](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera).

The command you used `npm i --save react-native-barcodescanner`
 is for install this lib to your project.

If you still want to use this lib, follow [this instruction](https://github.com/ideacreation/react-native-barcodescanner#usage):

Import:

```
import BarcodeScanner from 'react-native-barcodescanner';
```

Then use in your Component:

```
render() {
    return (
      <BarcodeScanner
        onBarCodeRead={this.barcodeReceived}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        torchMode={this.state.torchMode}
        cameraType={this.state.cameraType}
      />
    );
  }
```