# Multiple servers on Node.js

Tags: node.js, host, ports

I need to simulate four servers (with different host and port) on the same nodejs instance.

An example could be:

domain1:8000 -
domain2:8010 -
domain3:8020 -
domain4:8030 -

Can anybody please help me? 
Thanks

Comment: Create multiple servers (http or whatever), and make them listen to different ports...

Comment: How can I create them?

Comment: There are some examples of HTTP servers in the official doc : https://nodejs.org/api/http.html **edit :** I suggest you take a look at the links in there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js

Comment: How can you separate the host by the way ? Port I understand .

Answer (score 13):

I add an example with a possible solution for 2 servers using node.

First, you need to create a project:

```
mkdir simulate4servers
cd simulate4servers
npm init (entry point: index.js)
```

Install Express:

```
npm install express --save
```

Put the next files into the directory:

File app.js:

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const routes = require('routes.js');

app.use('/',routes);

module.exports = app;
```

File app2.js:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const app2 = express();
const routes = require('routes2.js');

app2.use('/',routes);

module.exports = app2;
```

File configDomain1.js:

```
module.exports = {
    port: 8000
}
```

File configDomain2.js:

```
module.exports = {
    port: 8010
}
```

File routes.js:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const api = express.Router();

api.get('/', (req,res)=>{
  res.send({message: 'Hello World!'});
});
module.exports = api;
```

File routes2.js:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const api = express.Router();

api.get('/', (req,res)=>{
  res.send({message: 'Hello World 2!'});
});
module.exports = api;
```

File index.js:

```
'use strict';

const app = require('./app')
const app2 = require('./app2')
const config = require('./configDomain1');
const config2 = require('./configDomain2');

app.listen(config.port, () => {
    console.log(`API REST running in http://localhost:${config.port}`);
});

app2.listen(config2.port, () => {
    console.log(`API REST running in http://localhost:${config2.port}`);
});
```

And finally, run it:

```
node index.js
```

Answer (score 9):

```
const express = require("express");

const server1 = express();
const server2 = express();
const server3 = express();

server1.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log("Server 1 is up and running on port 8000");
})

server2.listen(8010, () => {
    console.log("Server 2 is up and running on port 8010");
})

server3.listen(8020, () => {
    console.log("Server 3 is up and running on port 8020");
})
```

`express()` creates and returns an instance of a server. call it multiple times to create multiple instances. listen on different ports. that's all.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is correct https://stackoverflow.com/a/65159130/17576982.
But it should also include `server.use(cors())` else it may give error `cors policy no 'access-control-allow-origin'`.

Code to make multiple servers:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
server=express()
server2=express()
server.use(cors())
server2.use(cors())

server.get('/',(req,res)=>res.send({"server":"3001","name":"aakash4dev","data":"data 1"}))
server2.get('/',(req,res)=>res.send({"server":"3002","name":"aakash4dev","data":"data 2"}))

server.listen(3001)
server2.listen(3002)
```