# Communication between two applications running on different apache servers on different ports using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, apache

I want to create client server applications on same machine using simple html and javascript.

I have written 3 applications from which 2 are clients and remaining one should act as server.

I am running all these applications on different apache servers with different ports on same machine locally.

I want to access servers html page on request from any of the client.

How can I do it? What should I use for it?

Comment: Try this link, maybe this will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51620225/multiple-servers-on-node-js

Comment: To give the answer, I need to understand what kind of clients you have written? Ideally, communication should be done via web services in this case. Please elaborate this statement more "I want to access servers html page on request from any of the client."

Comment: Client is simply written in html and javascript as mentioned above.