# How do I open an a-frame app on my oculus?

Tags: aframe, oculus

I have an Oculus Quest. I'm checking out `a-frame` and want to test my app on the oculus. I don't see any instructions for doing so in the docs. It works fine in Chrome, but how do I develop for the Oculus with A-Frame?

Answer (score 0):

You need to open your website using the **oculus browser**. Open the browser, and type in the URL.

For developing You'll need a local server to serve the website and any assets. This itself is a huge topic, a simple solution could be using this [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server).

Alternatively You can also [create](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/) a simple [node](https://nodejs.org/en/) server, stackoverflow has a huge thread on starting with [node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js).

If you can access a website from you PC (where the server is running), then oculus connected with the same WIFI network should have no problems either.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the info here. So Oculus Browser is all I need to run the apps then, that part wasn't clear to me before. I'll see how that works!